# Colored Reflections with no Overall Color Change

Tags: lighting, reflection, emission

I am trying to make my own version of the Universal Intro; however, the color of the sun's reflections are white while I would like them to be more orange like the pic below.

[image: Universal Intro Reference]

I am attempting to make mine look as the prior picture. Here is a picture of mine that has only a white sun in the scene. It has only white reflections.

[image: White Sun Reference]

This being said, I can change the color of sun light; however it makes the whole scene orange and not just the reflections of the earth model. Another pic of this below.

[image: Red Sun Reference]

I know I could add in another sphere where the sun light is and use that as a real sun model to do this, but I would rather not. All I need to know is how to make the reflections of the earths water more orangish and not change the overall color of the scene and make it all red and hot looking. I've tried many ways with a light path node and a rgb mix node to test it out but nothing has worked. Any knowledge on this to help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello, I would try Leevmealone's solution, or use a small area light that you put close to the surface just to have the orange reflexion

Comment: As the above comment and the answer suggests, I wouldn't do this with one single light source for everything and you can be sure that the creators of the reference didn't do it with one light either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can helps you, here's what i've just achieved for you :

[image: Blender render Screenshot]

I've this result by adding a sphere with emission shader and transparent shader, mixed with a light path as factor. I've added the camera ray and the reflection ray with a Math Node. Like this, the Orange Sphere is only visible on the reflections and on the camera.

The entire scene :

[image: Blender Scene Quick render]

As you can see, the scene general lighting is actually white.

The shading nodes of the emissive sphere :
[image: Image of Blender shading Nodes]

An other solution can be to use a HDRI Map of the galaxy, with a red/orange sun, like this one : [HDRI Hub : HDR 180-7 Space Sky with Sun](https://www.hdri-hub.com/hdrishop/hdri/space/item/764-hdr-180-7-space-sky-and-stars) . But it can really mess up with the general lighting. It depends of the HDRI.

For me it's the best way to add an orange Reflection without affecting the general light. And you don't loss the others reflections.

Unfortunally, I don't know a good way to colorize all the reflections.

Comment: Very Brilliant! This definitely helps! There are actually many errors in the lighting of the official Universal Intro, which is actually cool to notice. I will definitely use this in my project as the solution, thanks for the great help mate!

Comment: I wonder how Universal did this  maybe they use this solution too